# Vue.js Store change state with an action

Tags: vue.js, state, vuex

I try to track and change an `active` state with my new setup Vuex store, which looks like this.

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    idToken: null,
    userId: null,
    user: null,
    active: null
  },
  mutations: {
    authUser(state, userData) {
      state.idToken = userData.token;
      state.userId = userData.userId;
    },
    storeUser(state, user) {
      state.user = user;
    },
    clearAuthData(state) {
      state.idToken = null;
      state.userId = null;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    setLogoutTimer({ commit }, expirationTime) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        commit("clearAuthData");
      }, expirationTime * 1000);
    },
    },
    login({ commit, dispatch }, authData) {
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:5000/login", {
          email: authData.email,
          password: authData.password,
          returnSecureToken: true
        })
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
          const now = new Date();
          const expirationDate = new Date(
            now.getTime() + res.data.expiresIn * 1000
          );
          localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.idToken);
          localStorage.setItem("userId", res.data.localId);
          localStorage.setItem("expirationDate", expirationDate);
          commit("authUser", {
            token: res.data.idToken,
            userId: res.data.localId
          });
          dispatch("setLogoutTimer", res.data.expiresIn);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          state.active = false; ### This does not work
          console.log(error);
        });
  }
});
```

I want an error message to pop up if the user is not active yet. This is why I try to change the active state. The code which leads to the error is commented in the code.

A method in my component should change it:

```
  methods: {
    onSubmit() {
      const formData = {
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
      };
      console.log(formData);
      this.$store.dispatch("login", {
        email: formData.email,
        password: formData.password
      });
    }
  }
```

When I enter a wrong password, Vue outputs this:

```
store.js?a259:86 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: store is not defined
    at eval (store.js?a259:86)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass state to vuex login action, for it to be available:

```
login({ commit, dispatch, state }, authData)
```

A better approach will be to use a mutation, since Vuex does not recommend changing active state outside of mutation handlers, and `state` in actions is used mostly for retrieving the value active state:

```
SET_ACTIVE(state, val){
  state.active = val
},
```

And:

```
login({ commit, dispatch }, authData){
    //...   
    commit('SET_ACTIVE', false)
}
```

Comment: thank you, very good explanation. Was already close before, but now it works :-)